# How to get the last element of a list matching a condition?

Tags: haskell

So I have a list list of numbers from 3 to 10. I want to get the last number that is bigger than 5 and smaller than 11.

```
*Main> greatestIndexInRange [3, 6, 7, 2, 5, 1, 0, 10, 2] 5 11
```

Comment: (I did not down vote.) You will get much better resonance, if you show people what you have tried.

Comment: How about you reverse the list and find the first?

Comment: Given the name of the function, do you need to return the index as well?

Comment: Also, what happens if none of the elements in the list fall in that range?

Answer (score 2):

You could [`reverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:reverse) the list, [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) by your predicate and select the resulting list's [`head`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:head) (which would be the last element in the original list) in linear time. Or you could select the [`last`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:last) element in the filtered list.

```hs
greatestIndexInRange :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> a -> a
greatestIndexInRange xs l h = head . filter (\x -> x > l && x < h) . reverse $ xs
```

```hs
greatestIndexInRange :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> a -> a
greatestIndexInRange xs l h = last $ filter (\x -> x > l && x < h) xs
```

For example:

```hs
greatestIndexInRange [3, 6, 7, 2, 5, 1, 0, 10, 2] 5 11
-- 10
```

Note that this is a partial function that will fail if no element in the list is in the given range, e.g.:

```hs
greatestIndexInRange [1, 2, 3] 5 11
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

As Chris suggested in the comments, you could also use [`find`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:find) from `Data.List` on the reversed list instead of `filter`+`head` for a slightly more elegant implementation:

```hs
import Data.List (find)

greatestIndexInRange :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> a -> Maybe a
greatestIndexInRange xs l h = find (\x -> x > l && x < h) . reverse $ xs
```

The function now returns a `Maybe`. This would also resolve the above issue of it being a partial function:

```hs
greatestIndexInRange [3, 6, 7, 2, 5, 1, 0, 10, 2] 5 11
-- Just 10
greatestIndexInRange [1, 2, 3] 5 11
-- Nothing
```

Comment: Why use `filter` and then select the head when you can just use [`find`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:15)? Also handily returns a `Maybe` type if nothing satisfies the predicate.

Comment: @Chris I was actually going to suggest `find` at first. I then decided on `filter`+`head`, since these functions are found in the standard Prelude and I wanted to keep the solution as simple as possible. However, I see your point and have extended my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'd honestly expect just `last $ filter p xs` rather than reversing the whole list.  I'd at least be confident that version ran with constant memory; I'm not convinced a reverse based solution does.

Answer (score 0):

This will let you do what you want on GHC 9.2 or newer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-}

import Control.Monad
import Data.Functor.Identity

lastJust :: forall f a b. Foldable f => (a -> Maybe b) -> f a -> Maybe b
lastJust p xs = foldr go id xs Nothing where
  go :: a -> (forall t. Applicative t => t b -> t b) -> forall t. Applicative t => t b -> t b
  go x acc z = maybe (acc z) (pure . runIdentity . acc . Identity) $ p x

greatestIndexInRange :: (Foldable t, Ord a) => t a -> a -> a -> Maybe a
greatestIndexInRange xs lo hi = lastJust (\x -> x <$ guard (x > lo && x < hi)) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to choose using `filter` with `last` than using `reverse` with `find`. The better solution depends on factors such as: the location in the list of the element we want, how many elements that match our predicate exist in the list, etc. You might decide on a case-by-case basis, but either solution is fine!

For instance, if the element we want is one and at the beginning, definitely reversing it and using `find` is worse than using `filter` with `last`.
Equally, if we have lots of elements that match our `filter`'s predicate, uniformly distributed across the list, you will be better off reversing the list and use `find`.

It would be wise to wrap your result in a `Maybe` in case there is none. The idea is that you need to get to the end of the list somehow. So either way, you will not get a better solution than linear time, unless the list is ordered in which case you could do a binary search.

```
import Data.List    
greatestIndexInRange :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> a -> Maybe a
greatestIndexInRange xs x y = find (\z -> z > x && z < y) (reverse xs)
```

Output:

```
*Main Data.List> greatestIndexInRange [3, 6, 7, 2, 5, 1, 0, 10, 2] 5 11
Just 10
*Main Data.List> greatestIndexInRange [1, 2, 3] 5 11
Nothing
```

Comment: What convinces you that *constructing* the reversed list will be faster than just evaluating such a cheap predicate?

Comment: The fact that `find` performs better that `filter` when searching for a single element. It is a cheap predicate indeed, but when it is applied to a huge list, say 1 million and you get in average half of elements filtered out, filter is also constructing a list for that. And head is linear, while reversing is linear but is just copy-paste. And find is O(k), where k <= n.

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip it is not so obvious. For example, if you consider a list made of only one good element that is located at the beginning, your strategy is worst. Because you will have to build the reverse list (`n` operations to go through and `n` to build) and go through again to get the last element (`n` operations to go through, and `n` to test), when the `last . filter` strategy build a one element list  (`n` operations to go through, `n` to test but just one build) and get immediately the solution (one operation)... `4n` for your strategy and `2n+2` for the other.

Comment: You are right. That is a particular case where it is worse. However, you are assuming the worst-case scenario, where the element is at the beginning. And you are also assuming that filter returns only one element, which may not be the case on an average basis. Of course, there are worst-case scenarios for `filter` with `last` as well. But your idea does prove that my solution is not so obvious, nor better in every case. So the real answer is "depends". I will re-edit my answer. Thanks @BenoîtFraikin!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following simple implementation.

```
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))

greatestIndexInRange :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
greatestIndexInRange [] _ _ = Nothing
greatestIndexInRange (x:xs) lo hi = res <|> if inRng x then Just x else Nothing
  where
    inRng x = x > lo && x < hi
    res = greatestIndexInRange xs lo hi
```

Alternatively, using `foldr` instead of recursion:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))

greatestIndexInRange :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
greatestIndexInRange nums lo hi = foldr f Nothing nums
  where
    inRng x = x > lo && x < hi
    f x res = res <|> if inRng x then Just x else Nothing
```

We remember the last value that is in the given range, and replace it with the current value if is in the given range. We also take into consideration the fact that there may not be a value in the given range.